# Test Case for React-Native in Functional Component

Tags: react-native, jestjs, mocha.js, enzyme, testcase

Difference between jest vs enzyme vs mocha.
 Which is better for writing test case in react native for functional Component ?

I want to know the difference between jest vs enzyme vs mocha.
Which is better for writing test case.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between jest and enzyme is that jest comes handy with JavaScript frameworks like react. Jest is used for unit testing in any JavaScript frameworks while enzyme is just for react. Enzyme has more mature functions that add more functionality and flexibility to your tests while jest is used for basic testing both functional and snapshot.

Jest is faster than mocha. Mocha was first designed to test node js applications. It also very mature.
For react or react-native use jest with Enzyme for functional and end to end testing.

Comment: is that possible to write testcase for Function in react-native for functional component by using jest with Enzyme.?

Answer (score 0):

Jest acts as a test runner, assertion library, and mocking library.

Enzyme is a JavaScript testing utility for React that makes it easier to assert, manipulate, and traverse your React Components’ output.

Diffrence:

1. Jest and Enzyme are both specifically designed to test React applications. While Jest can be used with any Javascript app, Enzyme only works with React.
2. Jest can be used without Enzyme to render components and run tests with snapshots; Enzyme merely adds functionality.
3. Enzyme can be used without Jest, but it must be paired with another test runner if Jest is not used.